# type mismatch; found : scalaz.stm.STM[E,A] required: scalaz.stm.STM[Nothing,A]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to simulate the orElse combinator for custom library.

Here is the code [link](https://github.com/rajcspsg/scalaz-stm/blob/master/src/main/scala/STM.scala#L75-L78).

When I compile the code I get error -

```
    type mismatch;
    [error]  found   : scalaz.stm.STM[E,A]
    [error]  required: scalaz.stm.STM[Nothing,A]
    [error]     stmEither.flatMap(either => either.fold(e => that, r => STM.point(r)))
```

I tried changing the signature of the function but that didn't help.

```
    final def orElse[E2 <: E](that: => STM[E2, A]): STM[E2, A] = {
        val stmEither: STM[Nothing, Either[E, A]] = self.attempt
        stmEither.flatMap(either => either.fold(e => that, r => STM.point(r)))
    }
```

I don't know how to make E2 both covariant and contra variant.
How to make this function compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two values and return one of them based on some condition then return type will be the lowest upper bound of these two types. It will be less specific than each original type.
Type `STM[Nothing,A]` says that it doesn't fail.
Type `STM[E2,A]` says that it can fail with an error of type `E2`.
It is impossible to make `orElse` non-failing if one of branches is error-prone.

<s>But this should work: 
`final def orElse[E2 >: E](that: => STM[E2, A]): STM[E2, A]`</s>

Also AFAIK scalaz ecosystem discourages using variance annotations.

Comment: I tried this But didn't help. I am still getting error  `50: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scalaz.stm.STM[E2,A]
[error]  required: scalaz.stm.STM[Nothing,A]
[error]     stmEither.flatMap(either => either.fold(e => that, r => STM.point(r)))
[error]                                                  ^
[info] scalaz.stm.STM[E2,A] <: scalaz.stm.STM[Nothing,A]?`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I checked the code and tried to make it compilable by adding variance annotations where needed. But finally I've seen `TVar[+A]` class. It contains `var value: A` so it has to be invariant.